# Auto-populate xml from directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Working on setting up a photo gallery that my client will be able to manage the contents through an open-source CMS solution.  The gallery on the site will be dynamically generated using XML.

The XML structure needs be formatted as shown below.  What I an trying to do is see if there is a way to automatically populate this file, whether through a script ran in Windows nightly to update this or through the C# backend file.

XML structure:

```
<image>
<title>Image Title</title>
</image>
```

Comment: Have you tried witting anything? yet, is your question regarding how to create XML files or how to loop through directories pulling property data out of files?

Comment: Sorry, disregard the <title>.  It will need to be something like <src> images/wedding_gallery/pic1.jpg</src>.  I need a way to look through the wedding_gallery directory and append files to the XML file.

Comment: As @Killrawr is asking, what **exactly** is your question?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use XmlSerializer

You can create an object to use for serialization

```
[XmlType("image")]
public class XmlImage
{
    [XmlType("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlType("src")]
    public string Source{ get; set; }

}
```

Then you can create a list of this object and serialize to an xml file.

```
// make a list of the images you want to save
List<XmlImage> images = new List<XmlImage>(Directory.GetFiles("imageDir")
    .Select(file => new XmlImage
                        { 
                           Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                           Source = file
                        }));

// create an XmlSerializer for you list type
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<XmlImage>));

// open file stream
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("destinationFile", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    // save list to xml
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, images);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I need, if I'm understanding it, since I would get this coded into my .cs file it should dynamically update whenever the page is visited?

Comment: You can call it whenever you need, it will overwite the existing file.